# What's wrong with my radius of convergence test?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Given $\sum \limits _{n=2} ^\infty \frac{(\ln x)^n} n$, find its radius of convergence $R$.

Using the ratio test, I arrived at

$$|\ln x| < 1 \implies e^{|\ln x|} < e^x \implies |x| < e \implies R = e .$$

This isn't the case, however. My teacher did:

$$|\ln x| < 1 \implies -1 < \ln x < 1 e^ \implies {-1} < x < e^1 \implies R = \frac{e-e^{-1}} 2 .$$

I figure that for the first discrepancy (where we decided to take care of the absolute value), I can't do one of the operations I did with an absoulute value sign. My best guess is that I can't cancel $e^{|\ln x|}$, although I'm not sure why -- I am looking for confirmation on if this is indeed the problem and why (or if the problem is somewhere else, where and why).

Secondly, how should I interpret the result? If $\ln x$ is only defined for $x>0$, then theoretically neither radius of convergence (wrong or right one) should work ($-\frac{e-e^{-1}} 2$ is a negative number). So how does this work out?

Comment: A radius of convergence is for a power series; your series is not one.

Comment: @zhw.: Letting $y = \ln x$ turns this into a power series in $y$, let's not be picky.

Comment: By picky you mean understanding the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error resides in the fact that, unlike what you were expecting, in reality $\textrm e ^{| \ln x |} \ne | \textrm e ^{\ln x} |$. To better understand why, choose $x = \frac 1 {\textrm e}$ and convince yourself that $\textrm e ^1 \ne |\textrm e ^{-1}| = \frac 1 {\textrm e}$.

To answer your second question, notice that your series is not a true power series in $x$. Letting $y = \ln x$, though, turns it into a power series in $y$, with the radius as computed by your professor.

To understand what this tells about $x$, remeber that $\ln$ is defined only for $x>0$, so once you solve the inequation $-R < \ln x < R$ for $x$, *don't forget to intersect* the solution set with $(0, \infty)$ to get the correct solution for $x$.

To conclude, your suspicions were correct, and you were pretty close to answer your question yourself, which is very good.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you see a negative argument for the logarithm? The fact is logarithm is defined only for poitive numbers, but its values can be negative, so:

$$|\log x|<1\iff -1<\log x<1$$

Observe that you have no problem at all applying the exponential now as it is defined in the whole real line. Also, use that $\;e^x\;$ is monotonic ascending:

$$-1<\log x<1\implies e^{-1}<x<e\implies R=\frac{e-e^{-1}}2$$

Comment: I thought that a radius of convergence meant "the span of valid (as in, causing convergence) values of x about a fixed point on the number line," usually with this fixed point being zero. For example, when I find a radius of convergence of 2, this means typically that $-2 < x < 2$. So why wouldn't a radius of $\frac{e-e^{-1}}{2}$ imply $-\frac{e-e^{-1}}{2} < x < \frac{e-e^{-1}}{2}$? And then, ln(x) will hold a negative value (the left side of the inequality is negative). Definitely I am convinced there's a gap in my understanding somewhere, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: As already commented, "radius of convergence" is more usually used for power series, which this series is not. Now, what you mention about the interval of convergence is for series around zero, which in this case is impossible because of the logarithmic function. Thus, your teacher's intention was, apparently, to "center" the series around the middle point of the interval of convergence, which is $\;(e^{-1},\,e)\;$ , and then as usual he takes this interval's length and divides it by two to get the radius. Anyway, we **all the time** are in the positive reals.